# Express measurable entropy in terms of Fourier coefficients of the measure

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, fourier-analysis, ergodic-theory

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle and $T:S^1\to S^1$ be a continuous map. Suppose $\mu$ is a $T$-invariant Borel probability measure on $S^1$, that is, $\mu(T^{-1}A)=\mu(A)$ for every Borel subset $A$ of $S^1$.  The Fourier coefficients 
$\{\hat{\mu}(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of $\mu$ is defined as
$\hat{\mu}(n)=\int_{S^1} \bar{z}^n \,d\mu(z)$.

Question: is there any way to express the measurable entropy $h_\mu(T)$ of $T$ in terms of
$\{\hat{\mu}(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$?

Comment: No. $\mu$ is invariant for both $T$ and $T^2$, but they have different entropies.

Comment: But $h_\mu(T)$ may have a different expression from $h_\mu(T^2)$ in terms of Fourier coefficients of $\mu$.

Comment: I cannot see how this can make sense. If you're allowing different expressions, then the entropy of $T$ is given by $h_\mu(T)\hat\mu(0)$.  The question should be: can you determine the entropy of the transformation using the Fourier coefficients **and nothing else**. The answer is you can't because $T$ and $T^2$ have the same invariant measure; so the same Fourier coefficients but different entropies.

Comment: I would interpret the question as follows: fix a transformation $T$, say the doubling map for concreteness.  Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the space of invariant measures.  Let $\mathcal{F}\colon \mathcal{M}\to \ell^\infty$ take $\mu$ to $\hat\mu$ and $h\colon \mathcal{M}\to [0,\infty)$ be the entropy function.  Then $h\circ \mathcal{F}^{-1}$ takes as input the Fourier coefficients of a measure and gives as output that measure's entropy.  This is a well-defined function on the space of sequences that are Fourier coefficients of an invariant measure, and it's reasonable to ask if it has a nice formula.

Comment: Of course changing the transformation $T$ would yield a different function $h\circ \mathcal{F}^{-1}$, but one can still ask the question.

Comment: I've stated to write a detailed answer, but I'll just change it to a comment after seeing this beautiful thread - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/98405/fourier-decay-rate-of-cantor-measures , I think the correct notion for this question should be the H-dim of the support of $\mu$, and you can find relation like that for Bernoulli shifts (a.k.a diagonal actions in your phrasing, like times $2$). Notice that for the usual Kronecker system, the entropy is $0$ although the dimension is full, so you indeed need this encoding of your system to make sense out of your situation.

Comment: Here we fix the map $T$.